# JPanel button not responding?

Tags: java, swing

I implemented the following code to get my character image to change when I clicked the button I created in the JPanel of Netbeans but it's not even being called (tested this by adding a line to print out in console but that's not even being printed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.out.println("Switch!");
        snowman.removeAllImages();
        snowman.addImage(image2);
```

Comment: don't compare Strings using the == operator. It's asking for trouble.

Comment: sorry, i pasted the wrong code. updated the question.

Comment: @zmi is there any errors in the console ??

Comment: no errors, just nothing shows up.

Comment: then debug your code

Comment: @zmi may be you have 2 buttons and you write code for button 2 but test it by clicking button1

Comment: Maybe you haven't registered the button event callback method correctly.

Comment: @Zmi Take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 1):

make try and catch statement in your action e.pritntrace it very helpful to debug you code and find your bugs hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

> to change when I clicked the button I created in the JPanel of Netbeans but it's not even being called (tested this by adding a line to print out in console but that's not even being printed.

You may want to ensure the following:

- Make sure the button you are interested to generate an event on click has already added as ***ActionListener*** object

**Example:**

- If you create an inner class for your ActionListener object,

  ```
  btn.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
  ```
- If you implements your current class with ActionListener,

  ```
  btn.addActionListener(this);
  ```
- If you create an anonymous ActionListener object,

  ```
  btn.addActionListner(new ActionListener(){          
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          //To do when button is clicked
      }
  });
  ```

---

I see that you created your own method to handle an action event:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
```

- If you do that, remember to fill up your codes in the `actionPerformed()` method of the ActionListener object which was added to your button.

**Example:**

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    jButton2ActionPerformed(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well explained by user3437460. If that doesn't help please copy more code here to understand it. Add a button listener and make sure you called your private method from it as shown below.

```
  btn.addActionListner(new ActionListener(){          
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         jButton2ActionPerformed(e);
     }
  });
```